# How to register methods without referring to the S3 ones

Tags: r, r-package

I had written some `R` functions that I wanted to convert to an `R` package. One of them is called for example `print.pretty.values` and another `print.empty.line`. Package builds and installs alright, but when I run the `check` function I get this warning:

**Found the following apparent S3 methods exported but not registered**

I have read the relevant documentation and I don't want to have a `print` function of my class `someClass`. I just need to export nicely (and without warning) a function that is called `print.something` or `plot.something.else` without it being understood as an S3 method and without me having to change the name. Is there a way to define this (in the function documentation or the `NAMESPACE` file?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all the names of the functions to have the underscore separator (`_`) instead of the dot (`.`), following the **tidyverse guidelines**: https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html

Note that the only case that they 'allow' dots in functions are when you write `function.class` or `class.name` and in my case it wasn't like that (`print.pretty.values` wasn't an S3 function - I just wanted to use the dot as a separator for words in general and thus I got warnings).